# Error defining the architecture of a CNN using Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to build a convolutional neural network to train word vectors that I obtained using word2vec previously.

The inputs of my CNN are sentences. Each sentence is an array of word vectors of size (1, 50). Thus, depending on N (the number of words in the sentence), the input is a vector of size (N, 50)

The CNN was defined as follows:

```
def word2vec2intentions(num_classes):
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(5, (2, 50), input_shape=(1, 50, None), activation='relu', strides=1, padding="valid"))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, 5)))
    model.add(Dense(5, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

However, when I try to run the function, I get this error :

> Using TensorFlow backend.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/zakariael/darija-word2vec/keras_intent_classifier.py", line 35, in 
>       model = word2vec2intentions(22)
>     File "/Users/zakariael/darija-word2vec/keras_intent_classifier.py", line 27, in word2vec2intentions
>       **model.add(Dense(5, activation='sigmoid'))**
>     File "/Users/zakariael/.virtualenvs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 469, in add
>       output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
>     File "/Users/zakariael/.virtualenvs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 569, in **call**
>       self.build(input_shapes[0])
>     File "/Users/zakariael/.virtualenvs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/core.py", line 825, in build
>       constraint=self.kernel_constraint)
>     File "/Users/zakariael/.virtualenvs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 87, in wrapper
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/Users/zakariael/.virtualenvs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 391, in add_weight
>       weight = K.variable(initializer(shape), dtype=dtype, name=name)
>     File "/Users/zakariael/.virtualenvs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/initializers.py", line 200, in **call**
>       scale /= max(1., float(fan_in + fan_out) / 2)
>
> **TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'**

Any idea how to fix this ? Thank you.

Comment: This architecture won't work, you cannot have one variable-sized dimension (None) and then use a layer that only accepts fixed-size inputs (Dense).

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I see. I thought using MaxPooling2D would reduce the output of the convolutional layer to a vector of fixed size (1, 5)
I replaced it by GlobalMaxPooling2D and it compiled with no errors. However, I don't really know the difference.